# ASP.NET MVC Binding Value in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Struggling to get a value from a drop down, to be passed into my controller for db inserting. 
It starts with a simple class for each item in the drop down.

```
 public class selectListUrgencyNum
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my view model I create a list of these objects as such..

```
public class createViewModel
{
    public Change Changevm { get; set; }

    public List<RequestType> rTypes { get; set; }

    public List<selectListUrgencyNum> listUrgency { get; set; }
}
```

Finally is my controller I populate this list to be displayed in the dropdown.

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {

        var urgNums = new List<selectListUrgencyNum>();
        for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            urgNums.Add(new selectListUrgencyNum() { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() });
        }

        var viewModel = new createViewModel
        {
            listUrgency = urgNums 
        };



        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I just used 1 - 5 as to make it simpler to understand.

My view creates the ddl like this.

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Changevm.UrgencyNum, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select class="form-control" id="select">
                <option> 1 = Least Urgent</option>
                @foreach(var item in Model.listUrgency)
                {
                    <option>@item.Text</option>
                }
                </select>
             @*How do I grab the value of what is selected??*@
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Changevm.UrgencyNum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         </div>
```

So I'm not sure how to get the VALUE of what the selected drop down option is, so that on my insert I can access it. Possibly a hiddenfor?

And if I use a hidden for, how would it look?

If already answered please link..

Comment: When you do a postback that value will be there. Set the name property on your select. Id is for jquery, name is for form post.

Comment: You really need to learn the basics. To generate a `<select>` use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Changevm.UrgencyNum, Model.listUrgency, ....)` assuming `listUrgency` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass just Text and Value, you can use `SelectListItem` class from System.Web.Mvc, which is there for passing items to dropdown lists.

```cs
public class CreateViewModel
{
    public Change ChangeVm { get; set; }

    public List<RequestType> Types { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> ListUrgency { get; set; }
}
```

In the Controller Create() method we create new ChangeVm also

```
var viewModel = new CreateViewModel()
{
    ChangeVm = new Change(),
    ListUrgency = urgNums
};

return View(viewModel);
```

On the View you can use `Html.DropDownListFor` extension method which will take care of creating the list with given items and proper name.

`Html.BeginForm` will take care of creating the form with proper "action" url, and method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChangeVm.UrgencyNum, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ChangeVm.UrgencyNum, Model.ListUrgency, "Choose Urgency...")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChangeVm.UrgencyNum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>
}
```

In the controller you can then use

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel vModel)
    {
        if(vModel?.ChangeVm?.UrgencyNum != null)
        {
            var chosenValue = vModel.ChangeVm.UrgencyNum;
        }

        return View(vModel);
    }
```

If everything goes well, you should have your value chosen in vModel.ChangeVm.UrgencyNum

Comment: This was my original intention! I like this.

Answer (score 0):

Add `name` attribute to your `select`.

```
<select class="form-control" id="select" name="selectedUrgency">
```

And within the posted action of the controller, lets say we have `Create2` action method. We can retrieve value from `Request` object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create2()
{
   var value = Request["selectedUrgency"];
}
```

Assuming that your given html has `<form>` tag with action url pointed to this action method.

Comment: I am using this instead of <form>.

@using (Html.BeginForm())

Comment: Yes its same. Just make sure it points to your action method with `HttpPost` attribute.

Comment: Unfortunetly it is still not grabbing the value.

Comment: My mistake. Working now!! Thanks.